# Tic-Tac-Toe Game Unknown column 'i' in field list MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-update, substring, tic-tac-toe

There is a part of my Tic-tac-toe game that gathers the beginning user's move and then updates the board. The move variable starts as a string so I use substring to get the column and row out of the string and put them into two variables i and j. Then I use an update statement to change the board. When I do so, however, it comes back with the error saying "Unknown column 'i' in field list". I don't understand why as I have declared the two variables at the top of the procedure.

EDIT: Here is the code for the table I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE `tictactoe_4213`.`grid` 
(`TTT` INT NOT NULL,
 `A` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `B` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 `C` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TTT`));

Insert into grid
values (1, null, null, null),
(2, null, null, null),
(3, null, null, null);
```

Here's the code:

```
create procedure tictactoe(input varchar(4))
begin

declare i varchar(1);
declare j varchar(1);
```

...

```
if input like 'bu__' then

  select substring(input, 3, 1) into i;
  select substring(input, 4, 1) into j;

if i not in ('A', 'B', 'C') then
    select 'Invalid Letter. Please enter a letter between A and C for the column.';
end if;

if j not in (1, 2, 3) then
    select 'Invalid Number. Please enter a number between 1 and 3 for the row.';
end if;

update grid
set i = 'U'
where ttt = j;

select * from grid;
end if;
```

Any help given will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a table definition for whatever table you are getting the error for? `mysql -u username -p` `use database` `describe table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had this schema, hypothetically. Well now I do.

```
create table grid
(
    ttt int not null
);
```

And this is my stored proc

```
drop procedure if exists asdf;

delimiter $$
create procedure asdf(input varchar(40))
begin

declare i varchar(1);
declare j varchar(1);

set i='a';

update grid
set i = 'U'
where ttt = j;

if i not in ('A', 'B', 'C') then
    select 'hello' as aMsg;
else
    select '2222' as aMsg;
end if;

end
$$
delimiter ;
```

And I call this

```
call asdf('ignore');
```

I get that exact error message

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'i' in 'field list'

So `i` is not a column in table `grid`

Comment: so seeing your update to the Question, I am right. You have no column `i` in table `grid`. Your update statement fails. Don't confuse variable names with column names.

Comment: so what do you suggest I do then? this is the only thing I could think of.

Comment: well you arent even supplying your stored proc. What do you want me to do

Comment: the rest of the procedure doesn't apply to this question. this is a separate if statement I am having trouble with.

Comment: I will say it for the 3rd time. you are doing an update to a table named grid setting a column in that table that **does not exist** (called `i`) to a value. It fails with the expected error code. This question is answered. Mark the answer accordingly